# Duda al hacer commit con mi programa de Python

Tags: python, git

Tengo una duda relacionada con esto de hacer commit, solo quiero hacer commit al archivo "Listas de números múltiplos 2,3 y 5.py" pero aparecen el resto de archivos y carpetas que se ven en la imágen. ¿Me podrían decir qué son? si son necesarios o no... Gracias de antemano (Uso Pycharm)

[image]

Comment: Si no me equivoco, la carpeta `.idea` es la configuración de Intellij IDE. La carpeta `venv` es el ambiente virtual en donde están instalados tu versión de Python y las librerías externas. Así que no, no deberías versionar esas carpetas. Lo que necesitas es usar el archivo [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) para ignorarlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¿Que son?**

`.idea` es un directorio con archivos del proyecto importado en tu IDE.

`venv` es un directorio con el Ambiente Virtual de Python que usas para tu proyecto con sus dependencias.

**¿Son necesarios?**

Yendo al grano, estos archivos **no son requeridos** para correcto versionamiento de tu proyecto.

Para el continuo y correcto funcionamiento de tu proyecto en tu ambiente local si son necesarios, dado que contienen las librerias y binarios (venv), y archivos de configuración de tu entorno de desarrollo (.idea).

La justificaciones respectivas son que `venv` puede ser muy pesado, y en la practica no se necesitan compartir todas las librerias directamente, si no que se [define un archivo de requerimientos de Python](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) llamado `requirements.txt`, que luego se puede importar facilmente mediante PIP. Por otro lado, tus configuraciones de tu IDE (PyCharm) son tuyas y probablemente otra persona tenga distintas configuraciones, lo cual en general se mantiene separado por higiene.

*¿Que hago?*

Te recomiendo crear un archivo `.gitignore` en tu proyecto, que ignore estos directorios en tus futuras interacciones con el proyecto. Esto se hace simplemente creando un archivo de texto en el cual se incluyen los archivos y directorios que quieres ignorar. Sin embargo, te recomiendo utilizar [algún ejemplo ampliamente disponible](https://gist.github.com/GhostofGoes/94580e76cd251972b15b4821c8a06f59) para partir, dado que aparte de incluir estos dos directorios que menciona, incluye otros que podrían aparecer a futuro. Basta con agregarlo a la carpeta de tu proyecto y `git` nunca mas te molestara con estos archivos y directorios.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación (aunque ciertas partes no entiendo jaja), puedo crear ese archivo directamente del PyCharm? o lo hago por separado y lo agrega en el GitHub? Otra duda, en el link que me adjuntastes está escrito al inicio `idea/`, igualmente agrego la linea `idea/*` al final del archivo? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Toda la razón, ya incluye todos los ignore que necesitas. Basta con colocarlo en la raiz de tu proyecto y listo!

Comment: Te recomiendo que entres en http://gitignore.io/, es una gran herramienta para generar los archivos .gitignore, solo escribes el lenguaje de programacion, tu IDE o editor de codigo y que usas un entoro virtual y te genera automaticamente el archivo ya solo lo guardas dentro de tu proyecto